# Optimal Time-Dependent Join Architecture

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I am developing a pipeline that will contain time-dependent joins. More specifically, the result of a join will be dependent on a Date field in one of the underlying tables.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Depending on the date value in Table A, R1 may map T1 or T2 in the resulting table.

My question is whether there exists a specific architecture or database that can efficiently handle these types of joins?

Answer (score 1):

Create an integer column that acts as a key for the date or create a date table where an integer is the primary key for the date. Either way, figuring out how to join to an integer would be more ideal than joining to a date.